# Making ng-keypress ignore tab

Tags: angularjs, accessibility, keypress

Essentially I have `ng-keypress` alongside everything that allows `ng-click`. However in Firefox this causes strange behaviour when tabbing through 'selectable' elements.

Is it possible to ignore a particular key when using `ng-keypress`; in this case, the tab key and how would it be possible?

http://plnkr.co/edit/gULRM1danxWQnijGHEkb?p=preview

Comment: Can you should some code? You should be able to trigger a controller method on a particular event. Then, inside the method, you can check if a certain key from the keyboard was pressed

Comment: @Avalanche Must dash but I added a plnkr. The checkboxes have it applied with the method attached. What I would want would be a way to exclude ng-keypress from working if it was tab pressed (even if it does nothing now, just in case).

Answer (score 0):

Keypress sends you a $event which contains a keychar you can take that and conditionally do whatever you want when de code is or not is a tab key

Comment: How would you modify that?

Comment: Thanks for the response. The problem with that is that it prevents the default action of tabbing which is all in all, a worse situation. Is there a way to apply something like this without removing the tab function?